# find a matrix $C \in \mathbb{F_2}$ such that

Tags: linear-algebra

Find an invertible matrix   $C  \in \mathbb{F_2}^{2\times 2}$ such that

$ C  \begin{bmatrix}  1 &1 \\ 0& 1 \end{bmatrix} C^{-1}=\begin{bmatrix}  x &0 \\ 0&y \end{bmatrix} $ for any $x,y \in \mathbb{F}$.

I was thinking about such a matrix  many times, but still I did not get  any matrix $C$  which  satisfied the  above given conditions.

Comment: $C$ should not be in $\mathbb F_2$ but $\mathbb F_2^{2 \times 2}$ I guess. Even better would be $C\in \text{GL}_2(\mathbb F_2)$, since $C$ should be invertible.

Comment: Do you know diagonalization of a matrix? Do you know what an eigenvector is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible. If there would exist such $C\in \text{GL}_2(\mathbb F_2)$, then the columns of $C^{-1}$ would be eigenvectors of $A=\begin{pmatrix}1&1\\0&1\end{pmatrix}$. But there is obviously only one eigenvalue of $A$ which is $\lambda=1$, with algebraic multiplicity $2$. On the other hand, $\lambda=1$ has geometric multiplicity $1$, so $A$ is not diagonalizable, i.e. there are no linearly independent eigenvectors.

Comment: thanks  u @Babelfish